How to set the state of a stateful widget from a navigated screen?
Consider the following Flutter app:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(useMaterial3: true),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  final List<String> _tabs = ['1', '2'];
  late TabController _tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(length: _tabs.length, vsync: this);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _tabController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Home'),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.settings),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => Scaffold(
                    appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Settings')),
                    body: ReorderableListView(
                      children: _tabs
                          .asMap()
                          .entries
                          .map(
                            (e) => ListTile(
                              key: Key(e.key.toString()),
                              title: Text(e.value),
                            ),
                          )
                          .toList(),
                      onReorder: (int oldIndex, int newIndex) {
                        setState(
                          () {
                            if (oldIndex < newIndex) {
                              newIndex -= 1;
                            }
                            _tabs.insert(newIndex, _tabs.removeAt(oldIndex));
                          },
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ],
        bottom: TabBar(
          controller: _tabController,
          tabs: _tabs.map((e) => Tab(text: e)).toList(),
        ),
      ),
      body: TabBarView(
        controller: _tabController,
        children: _tabs
            .map(
              (e) => Center(
                child: SizedBox(
                  width: double.infinity,
                  height: double.infinity,
                  child: FittedBox(child: Text(e)),
                ),
              ),
            )
            .toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

The intent of this app is to reorder the tabs in Home screen from Settings screen. Here is a record of a session with the app:

Now in the Settings screen, when a reorder takes place, the reordered entries don't stick, although the state changes when back in Home and back again in Settings. In more technical terms, in setState() in onReorder in ReorderableListView, the state being set is that of MyHomePage. How can I set the states of both MyHomePage and ReorderableListView in onReorder of ReorderableListView?

Your ReorderableListView is not on the same widget tree anymore and it won't be treated as a child of _MyHomePageState since you're pushing a new screen using Navigator.push.

@fixatd That's an excellent point. Indeed, if I move ReorderableListView somewhere into the Home screen, everything works: the tabs and the list items get reordered fine. But then a question arises: why with Navigator.push reordering the list sets the state of MyHomePage and not of ReorderableListView?

It's not that the setState works but going back to your MyHomePage would trigger a build with the updated _tabs. It would be a good idea to separate things out rather than having the tabs on the same widget.

The easiest and cleanest way to do this is by creating a separate widget for your destination/settings page. There, you can manage its own state, and you will need a callback to communicate with the parent widget to refresh the state.
Also you can achieve what you want using the StatefulBuilder widget and refresh both states.
Result:

Code:
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) =>
                      StatefulBuilder(builder: (context, stateSetter) {
                    return Scaffold(
                      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Settings')),
                      body: ReorderableListView(
                        children: _tabs
                            .asMap()
                            .entries
                            .map(
                              (e) => ListTile(
                                key: Key(e.key.toString()),
                                title: Text(e.value),
                              ),
                            )
                            .toList(),
                        onReorder: (int oldIndex, int newIndex) {
                          setState(() {
                            stateSetter(
                              () {
                                if (oldIndex < newIndex) {
                                  newIndex -= 1;
                                }
                                _tabs.insert(
                                    newIndex, _tabs.removeAt(oldIndex));
                              },
                            );
                          });
                        },
                      ),
                    );
                  }),
                ),
              );

